Multivariate ljung-box test: how to pick the degree of freedom for the chi-squared distribution?
I have a model with $p$ inputs and $q$ outputs. I want to check the autocorrelation of the output residuals, defined as $\epsilon(t) = y(t) - \tilde y(t)$, being $y$ the model output and $\tilde y$ the measured data.
This means that for each pair of output signal, I will have a residual $r_{ij}(\tau), i,j = 0, ... ,q$. Such residuals can be arranged in a $Mqq$ tensor $R_{ee}$ where the $(\tau,i,j)$ element is $r_{ij}(\tau)$ and $M$ are the considered lags. The value of $\tau$ ranges from $-M/2$ to $+M/2$.
I am trying to implement and use the ljung-box test, on each $r_{ij}(\tau)$ residuals, but I am not sure about the following:

how shall I pick the degree of freedom $h$ of the chi-squared distribution used for the test of each individual $r_{i,j}(\tau)$?
How shall I determine if that the overall vector $\epsilon(t)$ is uncorrelated with itself?

My guess would be the following:

$h=pq(M/2-1)$. This because we consider only the positive lags with the exclusion of the lag $\tau = 0$ in the test.
All the $pq$ ljung-box tests must not reject the null-hypothesis OR #passed_test/#failed_test must be higher than a certain threshold OR another idea could be to arrange all the p-values associated to all the $qp$ statistics in a matrix and evaluate such a matrix norm.

